# Add n extra text line to be translated

Tags: php

I am trying to add an extra text line to a php page that should be translate by a language php file.

the code is like this

```
<?php 
    if($phone) { 
?>
<b>
<?php 
    _de('Phone',49); 
?>
:</b><span>
<?php 
    echo $phone; 
?>
</span>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

Here is where i would like to add a line like 'sentence', 1045 (number of the entence translated. But everytime i try to add a php line it gives an error and everything stop working.

```
<div class="clear10"></div><a name="contactform"></a>
<div class="sendemail rad3 bluebutton l"<?php if ($err && $_POST['action'] == "contactform") { echo ' style="display: none;"'; } ?>><i><?php _de('Contact this escort',784); ?></i></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: This really isn't the way to go regarding development.  Inline PHP within HTML is bad practice and leads to code that is very hard to maintain.  You may want to try utilizing AJAX and component templates rather than inline PHP in your code.  You'll find it a lot easier to maintain and extend.

Answer (score 0):

try this, maybe the `_de(...)` needs to be printed

```
<b>
<?php 
    echo _de('Phone',49); 
?>
:</b><span>
```

Comment: thanks but this code works already...what I am trying to o is to insert a new sentence that will be translated. same as for the PHONE text

Comment: @user1763519 then show the new line that you added and the error that you were getting. that would make it easier to help you

Comment: I tried to add <?php echo _de('dont forget to mention blahblah, 1449); ?>